# segue from TableView

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm currently learning objective c and i'm trying to create a segue from a table view to a another view. and the code crashes at the prepareForSegue function.

heres the code

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"rowSelected"]){
    UIViewController *nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    nextViewController.title = @"newView";
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"rowSelected" sender:self];
}
```

My understanding for prepare for segue is that i initialize the next view there(?). but most tutorials i looked at only set a few configurations inside prepareForSegue.

is there anything obvious that im doing wrong? or perhaps someone can link a tableview + segue guide so i can follow through and find what i did wrong myself.

heres the error message, at least the part that i found to actually contain information

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[notesViewController length]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x469c'
```

Comment: That error means that you're asking for a length property from an object that doesn't have one. I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: that's all you have in your prepareForSegue ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Pita try this code

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"rowSelected"]){
    UIViewController *nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
nextViewController.title = [YourSomethingArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    }
```

Where **yourSomethingArray** find above from your code

```
cell.textLabel.text = yourSomethingArray[indexPath.row];
```